# Who is the msg.sender when calling function of ERC20 token contract inside a smart contract?

Tags: solidity

Here is a function in a smart contract to call `transferFrom` in ERC20 token contract.

```
pragma ^0.7.0

interface ERC20Token {
   function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
   function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
 }

contract MyContract {
  ...
  function depositEscrow(uint256 _value) payable external  returns (bool) {
        ...
        ERC20Token _fex = ERC20Token(contractFEX);  //<<==create instance of the ERC20 token contract with its address
        _fex.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), value);  //Who is msg.sender in transferFrom? is it the MyContract address?
        ... 
        return true;
    }
```

}

When executing `_fex.transferFrom()`, is `msg.sender` the address of `MyContract`?

Comment: No, it's the address of whoever called function `depositEscrow`.

Comment: The msg sender is the one who called the function. If u did directly with a transaction then it is u. If u called a contract and that contract called this method in MyContract then it is the address of the "between" contract.

Comment: Take care how the transferFrom method is implemented, because "inside" the code of transferFrom(in the Token Contract) the msg.sender is your contract

Comment: `Majd TL`, I thought inside `ERC20Token.transferFrom()`, the `msg.sender` is the `address(this)` which is the address of the MyContract instance. Is it true?. I understand that in function `depositEscrow()`, the `msg.sender` is the address of the caller who initializes the tx. Thanks.

Comment: just added the definition of ERC10Token interface to the post.

Comment: The first question yes its true , it should be the address of your contract. The second question yes but only if the transaction calling this function directly (first)

Comment: Check this could be helpful, but avoid to use tx.orgin it is very very bad https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/solidity-programming-essentials/9781788831383/3d3147d9-f79f-4a0e-8c9f-befee5897083.xhtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

msg.sender is the direct sender of the message. BUT it could also be a contract address so for example a contract that passed it along.

Comment: Hi `Tony`, just added definition of token interface to the post. I thought `msg.sender` is the contract address when executing `ERC20Token.transferFrom()`, Please correct if I am wrong.

Comment: Not always. As mentioned it COULD be a contract but could also be a user of a dapp for example. It is the senders address of what triggered the event.

Comment: In `@openZeppelin` ERC20 contract, when calling `transferFrom` from a function inside a contract, the msg.sender is the address of the contract. .

Answer (score 1):

I am doing something related to that here, and I found out that msg.sender will always return the address of the user who gave start to the transaction.

So if the valued is passed along to a hundred (or more) intermediary contracts, and you inspect the variable "msg.sender" on the last contract, it will still contain the address of the user who started the transaction rather than the address of the contracts.

By the way, right now i am looking for a solution to show me the address of the intermediary contact. I need it for a project.